# Adding Hamburger Button to SWRevealViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, swrevealviewcontroller

In the app I'm making I have a side menu that I used SWRevealViewController template to make. I made my own animated button to be the hamburger menu button so when its pressed the side menu will open. The problem is I can't figure out how to connect my animated button to the SWRevealViewController.

Here's the button code I made.

**Animated Button**

```
self.button = HamburgerButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30))
    self.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(home.toggle(_:)), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)

    let refreshButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Refresh,
    target: self, action: #selector(home.buttonMethod))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
```

and heres the button that was used for the SWRevealViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

if revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}

}
```

Ive done a lot of research but just can't find out how to do it. I need the button I made, which is the first code, to be the one to access the SWRevealViewController and to open and close the side menu rather then the button, which is the second code, that came with the SWRevealViewController template. Any help will be Awesome!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it. You can adapt this to your needs.

```
let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapDetected))
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
sideMenuButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
sideMenuButton.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

func tapDetected() {
    self.revealViewController().revealToggle(self)
}
```

Comment: Its giving me the error that `tapDetetected` is Object-C. is there anything i can change it to to work in swift?

Comment: I figured it out!!  you were right. I just had to mess around with it. Thanks man!